# How display image or shape from one cell in another cell

Tags: excel, image, shapes

I am looking for a custom vba function equivalent to the "=" operator to have one cell displaying the image or shape contained in another cell.

Comment: Images and shapes are not content within cells but are showed in a layer over the cells and only anchored to cells. So there is not such a functionality with formulas since formulas cannot access the graphics layer. Only VBA or other programming languages can do that.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I have edited my question therefore

Comment: OK now you know that VBA is needed. So what have you tried? What was the result of your searches about "Excel VBA copy shape"? Hint: Using a function as a User Defined Function (UDF) will be difficult and problematically. So an approach which uses a Sub triggered by somewhat will be preferable. Please try your own effort and ask concrete questions if you are stuck.